# Is it possible to encrypt id from the resource in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, encryption

Let's I give one Example to more explanation.

Here is one layout file

**abc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="0x7f10014b"
    android:layout_height="-2"
    android:layout_width="-1"
    android:orientation="0" 
    android:padding="5dp" 
    android:weightSum="1.0">

    <TextView 
        android:id="0x7f10014c"
        android:layout_height="-2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.99" 
        android:layout_width="-2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="0x7f10014d"
        android:layout_gravity="10"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="0x7f0200b2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

as you can see in the layout file the id is encrypted by the algorithm. and it will store in id.xml folder which is inside the values folder.

**id.xml**

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="action_location">false</item>
    <item type="id" name="action_tile">false</item>
    <item type="id" name="action_filter">false</item>
    <item type="id" name="action_share">false</item>
</resources>
```

for the upper thing if can write java code then it's logic like below.

for the access of `LinearLayout` here is let's say `LinearLayout` is encryted with value `00ff7des`.

So the Global declaretion is :

```
LinearLayout 00ff7des;
```

inside OnCreate method

```
00ff7des = (LinearLayout)findViewById(0x7f10014b);
```

So I am new to Android. Is there any way to doing this. As per my thought this is possible but how to encrypt that i don't know. can anyone tell me what should I Do for that. Or which are the encrytion technique we can apply for android.

Any Help be Appreciated.

Comment: why would you want to encrypt the ID?

Comment: @Yazan for the cracking purpose ?

Comment: to be honest it's the first time i come to this idea, not sure if it will be helpful. anyways, can you be more specific on your question, you know android is just java in many aspects, so you can encrypt, decrypt as if you are writing java codes.

Comment: @Yazan I update my question with explantion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use software like DexGuard to achieve this. https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard

You can use ProGuard for free and it does obfuscate and minimize the code already, so reverse engineering of your app will be a lot harder.

Comment: can you give me the explantion with code from the link I can't understand.

Comment: Basically what it does it changes the names of the variables and methods so code like this 
`String name = user.getName()` might become `String a = x.b();` or something else that is not easy to reverse engineer. Also this does slim down your APK size by removing unused methods and classes from libraries you use.

Comment: let me first try your answer then i will come to you.